# Restrict Postfix delivery options for local messages via sendmail/postdrop

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have a staging server running Postfix, which I want to only set up to deliver mail to example.org.  If we are testing a function that sends e-mail, we want to be able to know that we won't accidentally send any test messages out to anyone outside our test domain.

All mail is sent from this server to a smarthost for delivery.

I have set up

```
relay_domains = example.org
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination
```

This means the server only relays for example.org by SMTP.  However, using mail(1) on the server, it will deliver for all addresses.  How can I restrict this to the relay_domains only?

Comment: Is the domain example.org on the same machine or does it have to be relayed to some other machine ?

Comment: It has to be relayed to an external smarthost.  No local accounts exist on this machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None other than esteemed Postfix author Wietse Venema [gives us the answer](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/postfix/2010-01/0827.html):

> Perhaps with a transport table, taking
>   advantage of its special syntax:
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf
>     transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
>
> /etc/postfix/transport:
>     example.org :
>     *      error:we do not deliver this domain
> ```
>
> The above will reject SMTP mail, and
>   bounce local submission, for domains
>   other than example.org.