# Postfix / How to allow sending only to one IP

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix server that is on a public IPV4 address.
I want to allow postfix to send emails ONLY to this IPV4 address (the same).
Tried many things but no success...

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

++EDIT01 : there are several domains on this server, and I want ONLY ONE domain to send emails to itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i disable outbound mail in postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/271260/how-can-i-disable-outbound-mail-in-postfix)

Comment: The alternative, block egress port 25 in your firewall rules and/or security groups or https://serverfault.com/a/106447/37681

Comment: if @HBruijn's comments do not answer your question please explain why you want to use the public IP address

Comment: @jasen there are several domains on this server, and I want ONLY ONE domain to send emails to itself

Comment: so use localhost, you don't need the public address involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Postfix transport map to configure the delivery behavior for the specific domain.

Create a new file called /etc/postfix/transport

```
example.com smtp:[1.2.3.4]
```

Replace example.com with the domain that you want to restrict, and 1.2.3.4 with the IPv4 address of your Postfix server.

Create a new file called /etc/postfix/restrictions

```
/^example\.com$/     OK
/^example\..*/       REJECT
/.*@example\.com$/   OK
/.*@example\..*/     REJECT
```

Replace example.com with the domain you want to restrict. This file will help you restrict the domain to send emails only to itself.

Add the following lines to your /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/restrictions
```

Run the following commands to compile the transport map and reload Postfix:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
sudo systemctl reload postfix
```

Now, the specified domain should only be able to send emails to the same IPv4 address, and other domains should continue to operate as before.